# Unary operator precedence in Operator Precedence Parser

Tags: parsing, operator-precedence

I am implementing a Recursive Descent Parser to parse a C-like language. For parsing expressions, I was using an Operator Precedence parser, but I wanted to make the precedence of some binary operators higher than the unary operators. How can I do this?

Comment: Are you using recursive descent or operator precedence? They're not at all the same thing. It would be better if you showed what you trued, exactly, and explained why it didn't satisfy your requirements.

Comment: I was following the recursive descent-esque model described here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator-precedence_parser#Pseudocode. My problem is that this approach only allows binary operators and unary operators must be parsed as part of the "Primary expression".  However, in C++ the "::" operator has higher precedence that all unary operators. How can I achieve this without having to write an LR parser?

Comment: `::` is not an operator in terms of that algorithm, because its arguments are id's, and nothing else. `a::(b::c)` doesn't make any sense, so including `::` in an expression grammar is a category error. You can just make a non-terminal, `qname::= [ID] {"::" ID}`. In this sense, it differs from `.` (and `->`) which are effectively unary postfix operators. (The operand, which comes first, is an `expression`. What comes afterwards is an ID, not an arbitrary expression.) Precedence climbing, like many other op-prec techniques, cannot distinguish non-terminals, so it applies to grammars in which...

Comment: ...all the non-terminals could be replaced with a single non-terminal, relying on precedence to disambiguate. An example of a binary operator binding more tightly than a unary operator is Python's exponentiation operator. In Python, `not` bunds even more loosely but the way Python parses it is, imho, incorrect so `**` is a better example

Comment: If you ask a more specific question, I'll answer it more specifically. (You can modify the precedece-climbing algorithm to handle intermediate precedence unary operators, although as with any expression grammar you need to watch out for punned operators, so you could ask about that, too, if you wanted to.) But I have to ask: what's the problem with writing an LR grammar?